# Image edit and mysql

Tags: php

I have a simple table for reference page:
  id    name    description     image

In reference.php, A form upload image to a folder and save image's name in image section. 
In reference.php?action=edit page I want to edit the image. What is correct way to edit? Uploading another image and update the table? 
Functions:

```
function editRef() {
    ?>
    <?php 
     $row = queryWithID('reference');
     EpUpload();
     ?>
    <div class="form">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
          <li><label>Name</label></li>
          <li><input name="refname" type="text" class="inp" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /></li>
          <li><label>Description</label></li>
          <li><textarea name="reftext" cols="" rows=""><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea></li>
          <li><label>Image</label></li>
          <li><input name="refile" type="file" /></li>
          <li><label>Sıra</label></li>
          <li><input name="reforder" type="text" class="inp"/></li>
          <li><input name="refsubmit" type="submit" value="Edit"  class="int"/></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
    <?php
}

function EpUpload() {
    $refsubmit = safe_mysql('refsubmit');
    $reftext     = safe_mysql('reftext');
    $refname     = safe_mysql('refname');
    $reforder    = safe_mysql('reforder');
    $refile    = $_FILES['refile']['name'];
    $tmp         = $_FILES['refile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType  = $_FILES['refile']['type'];
    $path      = SITE_ROOT."uploads/images/";


    if($refsubmit){
    $require_fields = array("$reftext","$refname", "$reforder");
        if(checkBlank($require_fields)){
            echo "<p class='not'><span>Please fill all inputs!</span></p>";
        }
        else{
      move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$refile);
        $query = "UPDATE reference SET name = '$refname', order='$reforder' description = '$reftext', image = '$refile' WHERE id = $id ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
      if(mysql_affected_rows () == 1){
        echo "<p class='ok'><span>rBlah blah</span></p>";
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
        }
}
}

function queryWithID($table){
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])){ $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);}
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id= $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);
return $row ;
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this way is correct.

Well, how I do it:
note this code:

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] AND !$_FILES['userfile']['error']) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$cfg['upload_path'].$id.".jpg");
}
```

it will move the file only if there was a file and no error.
Note 3 parts of this script.

Ahhh almost forgot it!
I do not save the original file name but use id for it.

```
<?
include 'cfg.php';
$table=$cfg['db_table'];
$data=array();
$pic='';
$fields=array('title','section','price','annot','visible');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { 
  if ($id=intval($_POST['id'])) {
    $query="UPDATE $table SET ".dbSet($fields)." WHERE id=$id";
  } else {
    $query="INSERT INTO $table SET ".dbSet($fields);
  }
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  if (!$id) {
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
  }
  if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] AND !$_FILES['userfile']['error']) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$cfg['upload_path'].$id.".jpg");
  }
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
  exit; 
} 
include $cfg['tpl_header'];

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { 
  $LIST=array();
  $query="SELECT * FROM $table"; 
  $res=mysql_query($query);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $LIST[]=$row;
?>
<br><a href="?id=0">Add item</a><br><br>
<? foreach ($LIST as $row): ?>
 <li><a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['title']?>...</a>
<? endforeach ?>
<?
} else { 
  if ($id=intval($_GET['id'])) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=$id"; 
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v);
    if ($row['visible']) $row['visible']=" checked";
    if (is_readable($cfg['upload_path'].$id.".jpg")) $pic=$id.".jpg";
  } else {
    foreach ($fields as $k => $v) $row[$v]=''; 
  }

?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border=0>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="title" size="100" value="<?=$row['title']?>"></tr>
<tr><td>Price</td><td><input type="text" name="price" size="100" value="<?=$row['price']?>"></tr>
<tr><td>Descr</td><td><textarea rows="20" cols="80" name="annot"><?=$row['annot']?></textarea></tr>
<tr><td>Visible</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" value="1" checked></tr>
</table>
<?if(isset($row['id'])):?> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?endif?>
Picture:<input name="userfile" type="file" /><br>
<input type="submit">
<br><br>

<a href="?">Back to list</a>
</form>
<? if($pic): ?>
<img src="img/<?=$pic?>">
<? endif ?>
<? 
  } 
include $cfg['tpl_footer'];

?>
```

Comment: But how can I show value in file input? It doesnot show anything
<input name="refile" type="file"  value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />

Comment: @Felicita Yes it doesn't. But why? You don't need it. To leave old image in the database just leave this field blank.

Comment: @Felicita are you asking for your own code or for the some third-party code? If first - just add a code to handle empty field

Comment: @Felicita that's quite strange code, it does show the form and run it's handler simultaneously. But it must be separate processes. I can't see "query was empty" error in this code

Comment: what is wrong and strange inmy code? Can you help me about correction my code please? Or any example for this?

Comment: @Felicita well I've edited my answer as well :) It is not full working code as it use some own functions, but can show you the idea.

Comment: @Felicita feel free to ask if got any problems with this code